# Rewriting SEO friendly URLS using https

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

I have recently set up a domain with an SSL certificate and I would like to accesss the entire site via https instead of http.

I am currently using RewriteEngine and a php script called `page.php` to handle URL parameters in order to include the correct page content with SEO friendly URLs like the following.

```
www.example.com/page.php?venue=someplace&artist=singer
```

would become:

```
www.example.com/someplace/singer
```

My `.htaccess` file contains the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?venue=$1&artist=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?venue=$1&artist=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?venue=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?venue=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

When accessing the site via https the rewrites don't seem to work correctly. The user is directed to my 404 error page. Adding `https://www.example.com/` before `page.php` in the .htaccess file does not have the desired effect. Instead the user is forwarded to `https://www.example.com/page.php?venue=test&artist=test`. Although this is not the SEO friendly URL I require, this URL loads page content correctly, so can only assume the problem must be in my .htaccess file.

I have searched for solutions and found the following which I have tried including the in my `.htaccess`, but without any success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [Rs,L]
```

Does anyone have a solution to enter into my `.htaccess` file to enable my to access the site via https?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# enforce https and www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# skip further rules for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?venue=$1&artist=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?venue=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I will appreciate a comment for the downvote here. Is there anything wrong with this answer?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava As search engines see https://www.example.com and http://www.example.com as different pages, do I need to also used 301 redirects or will this handle that problem too?

Comment: Check updated code, this will enforce `https` and remove `www`. Once this is working just change `302` to `301`.

Comment: If I were to want to keep the www, would I simply add www to domain name? @anubhava

Comment: Hi @anubhava Thanks for all your help. I am getting a redirection loop error.

Comment: Still no luck. @anubhava

Comment: Are there more rules also and are you using some CMS framework? Open your page in Firebug and report what redirects you get in Net tab.

Comment: It's a site I designed myself from scratch. Firefox does not let me load in https as 'This Connection is Untrusted' for some reason

Comment: You can trust the cert by ignoring the warning.

Comment: I get 21 'GET www.example.com 302 Found' the site is hosted on shared hosting and the service provider installed the SSL for me. I have noticed that the IP address the site now resolves to is different. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes definitely that looks like a problem since `http` and `https` are not pointing to same host and same directory.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way round that. Perhaps need to upgrade my hosting

Comment: I hope I havn't wasted your time. I will give you a tick when I get it working!

Comment: Hope you get it working soon. I can assure that these rules are correct and tested.

Comment: looking at the DNS records I see that the service provider has changed the 'A' records for www and @ to the new IP address and there is a wildcard 'A' record pointing at the old server.

Comment: Sorry I don't have server admin knowledge to assist you in that.